# table missing after upgrade to 2.3

Tags: magento2, database

I upgraded to Magento 2.3 and got this error on the top of the admin page.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'a15809b3_m2.magento_bulk' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   `main_table`.*, (IF( (SELECT count(*) FROM magento_operation WHERE
>   bulk_uuid = main_table.uuid ) = 0, 0, (SELECT MAX(status) FROM
>   magento_operation WHERE bulk_uuid = main_table.uuid) )) AS `status`
>   FROM `magento_bulk` AS `main_table` WHERE (`user_id` = '1002') ORDER
>   BY FIELD(status, 2,3,0,4,1), start_time DESC

where can I get this to add to the database?

Comment: run setup:upgrade, reindex and cache commands

Answer (score 2):

You should create the table following these instructions below:

```
CREATE TABLE `magento_bulk` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Bulk Internal ID (must not be exposed)',
  `uuid` varbinary(39) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Bulk UUID (can be exposed to reference bulk entity)',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID of the WebAPI user that performed an action',
  `user_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Which type of user',
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Bulk Description',
  `operation_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Total number of operations scheduled within this bulk',
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Bulk start time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MAGENTO_BULK_UUID` (`uuid`),
  KEY `MAGENTO_BULK_USER_ID` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Bulk entity that represents set of related asynchronous operations';
```

Is it okay?

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve this issue,you ***need to create flat table*** **`catalog_category_flat_store_1`**.

disable magento ***Catalog Flat for Category*** from `Admin>Store>Catalog>Catalog>Use Flat Catalog Category` make it **NO**

[image]

Then Flush Magento Cache by `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Then you should **drop table** `catalog_category_flat_store_1`, if it is *exists in db*  by `drop table catalog_category_flat_store_1`

Next, enable ***Catalog Flat for Category*** by `Use Flat Catalog Category` make it yes

Final,you need to indexing from magento cli : `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`